# Java regex to match previous 2 lines of a pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, sublimetext2

```
something Line One
something Line two 
Last annotated on December 31, 2014

I don't care what is in between. Anything can go here. Any number of lines
I don't care what is in between. Anything can go here. Any number of lines

Something Line three
something line four
Last annotated on November 15, 2014
```

I want to write a regex to match

```
something Line One
something Line two 
Last annotated on December 31, 2014
```

and

```
Something Line three
something line four
Last annotated on November 15, 2014
```

I have written below regex that works on Sublimetex, but same regex does not work on java.

```
.*\n.*\nLast annotated on \w* \d{2}, \d{4}
```

Below is the java code that does not match the pattern.

```
String regex = ".*\\n.*\\nLast annotated on \\w* \\d{2}, \\d{4}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Pattern and Matcher classses with `find` function.

```
String s = "something Line One\n" + 
        "something Line two \n" + 
        "Last annotated on December 31, 2014\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "I don't care what is in between. Anything can go here. Any number of lines\n" + 
        "I don't care what is in between. Anything can go here. Any number of lines\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "Something Line three\n" + 
        "something line four\n" + 
        "Last annotated on November 15, 2014";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*[\\r\\n]+.*[\\r\\n]+Last annotated on \\w* \\d{2}, \\d{4}").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
something Line One
something Line two 
Last annotated on December 31, 2014
Something Line three
something line four
Last annotated on November 15, 2014
```

Comment: The actual problem is new line chars are \r\n as I'm reading from a file in windows 7.